# How to revoke amplify AppSync session - Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-android

My android app is using AWS Amplify for authentication, data storage & syncing (Cognito, S3, AppSync, API Gateway). 
[Amplify Android](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android)

I want to prevent the user to sign into multiple devices, I have a table `Configuration` and save the `device id` on it after a successful sign in, data syncing (get data from cloud) is done on the sign in process.

I added a logic on sign in process to check if the `device id from cloud` matches the `current device id`, if it doesn't match, the user will be asked if he wants to switch to the new device.

The problem I'm facing is that if `user1` is currently logged in to `Device A` and `user1` tries to log in to `Device B` and proceed to switch, the user is now logged in to 2 devices.

I didn't see any service or an api on amplify to notify `Device A` if the user logs in to another device, so I'm thinking if it's possible to revoke AppSync token/session on `Device A` so even user did a transaction on `Device A` it will not sync to the cloud.

Cognito Global sign out doesn't work: [Amplify Auth globalSignOut](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib-v1/auth/signOut/q/platform/android/)

I want an efficient way to solve this as the amplify services have fees.

**Amplify version im using is: 1.36.1**